# Metadata database design

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I am trying to store meta data about a document into a SQL Server. The document are stored into a document archive, and returns back an identifier so I can get back that document by asking the archive to get the document by identifier.

Our user would like to be able to search for this document based on different meta data. The meta data could be 1 attribute or 5 depending on the document type, and the users should be able to create new document types from a admin site.

I can see two solution here. One is that each documenttype gets it's own metadata table, where all metadata attributes are predefined, and if one should be added a new column needs to be created. And if a new documenttype is created a new metadata table needs to be created. Our DBA will freak out with a solution like this, and I also see a problem with indexes. Because if the documenttype has 5 different meta data attributes it needs to be searchable with 1 or 4 of them specified in the search. Then I would need to write index for all the different combinations of possible searchs.

here is an example (fictiv)

```
    |documentId | Name     | InsertDate | CustomerId | City   
    | 1         | John     | 2014-01-01 | 2          | London
    | 2         | John     | 2014-01-20 | 5          | New York
    | 3         | Able     | 2014-01-01 | 10         | Paris
```

I could here say:

- Give me all documents where Name = 'John'
- Give me all documets where Name = 'John' And CustomerId = 5
- Give me all document where InserDate = '2014-01-01' and City = 'London'

This will be 3 differnet indexes and then I haven't coverd all possible combinations. This isn't practical.

So I am look in to the evil 'EAV' (anti)pattern.

So instead of having the metadata as columns I can have the as rows.

```
|documentId | MetaAttribute | MetaValue
| 1         | Name          | John
| 1         | InsertDate    | 2014-01-01
| 1         | CustomerId    | 2
| 1         | City          | London
| 2         | Name          | John
| 2         | InsertDate    | 2014-01-20
| 2         | CustomerId    | 5
| 2         | City          | New York
| 3         | Name          | Able
| 3         | InserDate     | 2014-01-01
| 3         | CustomerId    | 10
| 3         | City          | Paris
```

Here it's simple to create one index om MetaAttribute och metaValue, and it's covered. If a new documenttype is created, new metadata can be created with that documenttype into a MetaAttributeTable (that contains all MetaAttribute for the different documenttype). So no need to create new tables or coulms if a new documenttype is added or if a new attribute is added to a documenttype. Instead all MetaValues most be strings :( and the SQL Query to find the document id is a bit more complicated.

This is what I figured out. (In this example the MetaAttribute is a string, but would be an ID to the MetaAttribute Table)

```
SELECT * FROM [Document]
  WHERE ID IN (SELECT documentId FROM [MetaData]
                      WHERE  ((MetaAttribute = 'Name' AND MetaValue = 'John')
                         OR (MetaAttribute = 'CustomerId' and MetaValue = '5'))
                      GROUP BY [documentId]
                      HAVING Count(1) = 2)
```

Here I need to ask if the Name = 'John' and CustomerId = 5. I do that by finding all records that have Name = 'John' and CustomerId = '5' and the Group it on the documentId and count number of items in the group. If I got 2 then both Name = 'John' and CustomerId = '5' is true for this search. Return the documentId and use that to retrive information about the document, like the document archive storage id.

There should be a better SQL statement for this isn't there?

So my question is. Is there a better approche than these 2. Is the EAV-pattern so bad that I should stick with the first approche and have a Freaked out DBA and "ten millions of indexes"

We are talking about a system that will have around 10-20 millions of new records each month, and contain data for at least 3 years.... So the tables will be preatty big and good indexes are neccasary for performance.

Best Regards
Magnus

Comment: Have you thought of using Full Text Search instead of multiple indexes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server 2008+ offers three related features for dealing with such cases:

- [Sparse Columns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280604.aspx) which allow you to define hundreds of columns even if only a subset are used at a time
- [Column Sets](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280521.aspx) allow you to group these columns and treat them as a group
- [Filtered indexes](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280372.aspx) can index only the rows that actually have values in them.

These features allow you to work with more-or-less normal SQL statements to handle all metadata columns.

These features were specifically added to address the EAV/metadata scenario.

**EDIT**

If you have a limited set of attributes that are always filled, there is no need for Sparse Columns or the EAV anti-pattern either.

You can create your tables as you normally would and add indexes to optimize the real workload you encounter. Certain types of queries will occur far more often than others and SQL Server's Index tuning advisor can propose the indexes and statistics to use based on a trace captured using SQL Server's Profiler.

It's quite possible that only a subset of the columns will accelerate searches and the rest can be added as `include` columns in the index.

**Full Text Search**

A more powerful option is to use SQL Server's [Full Text Search](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx). This will allow you to execute queries using arbitrary attributes. This is another technique using by document/content management systems, ERPs and CRMs to handle arbitrary attributes.

With FTS you simply specify the columns to include in one FTS index and don't have to create separate indexes for each attribute.

You can use FTS predicates in SELECT queries like this:

```
SELECT Name, ListPrice
FROM Production.Product
WHERE ListPrice = 80.99
   AND CONTAINS(Name, 'Mountain')
```

This can result in much simpler queries (you just write a modified select) and administration (no worries about column order in indexes, only one FTS index to manage)

Comment: Sounds intresting, I will check them out. Thanks.

Comment: I have read about the sparse columns and it looks like this is if I have a lots of NULL value in the coulmns. I will not have that, all columns will have a value. So if I have a table: docTypeInvoice_MetaData. Then all columns in that table will have values. I check out Filterd Indexes but couldn't se how they should help me. I don't want to filter on data, I want to create a Index that performs good no mather what query I send to it. If I use 1 or 4 of the columns in the WHERE statement :)

Comment: Then you don't really need EAV either. You don't need "10 million indexes" or a freaked-out DBA. Just select the appropriate indexes according to your real workload. Full-text searching can cover ad-hoc queries.

Comment: I am going for specific columns in each tables, and then monitoring what queryries are most frequent and create index for these and the use FTS for the others that isn't used that much..

Answer (score 3):

The EAV model is appealing if you have unbounded attributes--that is, anyone can set up anything as an attribute. However, it sounds from your description that this is not the case--the possible document attributes come from a known and fairly limited set. If this is the case, routine normalization suggests the following:

```
--  One per document
CREATE TABLE Document
 (
   DocumentId  --  primary key
  ,DocumentType
   ,<etc>
 )

--  One per "type" of document
CREATE TABLE DocumentType
 (
   DocumentTypeId  --  pirmary key
  ,Name
 )

--  One per possible document attribute.
--  Note that multiple document types can reference the same attribute
CREATE TABLE DocumentAttributes
 (
   AttributeId  --  primary key
  ,Name
 )

--  This lists which attributes are used by a given type
CREATE TABLE DocumentTypeAttributes
 (
   DocumentTypeId
  ,AttributeId
  --  compound primary key on both columns
  --  foeign keys on both columns
 )

--  This contains the final association of document and attributes
CREATE TABLE DocumentAttributeValues
 (
   DocumentId
  ,AttributeId
  ,Value
  --  compound primary key on DocumentId, AttributeId
  --  foeign keys on both columns ot their respective parent tables
 )
```

A tighter model with more robust keys could be implemented to ensure at the database level that an attribute cannot be assigned to a document with an “inappropriate” type.

Queries have to use joins, but (presumably) only the `Documents` and `DocumentAttributes` tables will ever be large. An index on on (AttributeId + Value) facilitiate lookups by attribute type, and depending on cardinality an index on (Value + AttributeId) could make searches for specific attributes quite efficient.

---

(Edit)

Ooh, clever, I created two tables with the same name.  I've renamed the last one to DocumentAttributeValues. (Free advice is clearly worth what you paid for it!)

This shows how ugly these systems can get in SQL, as you have to “look up” both attributes separately. On the plus side you don’t have to worry about “does this type go with this document”, as those rules have (better had) been applied when the data was loaded. Two examples:

This one spells everything out in joins, and as such I think it might perform worse than the next:

```
--  Top-down
SELECT do.DocumentId
 from Documents do
  inner join DocumentAttributes da1
   on da.Name = 'Name'
  inner join DocumentAttributeValues dav1
   on dav1.AttributeId = da1.AttributeId
    and dav1.Value = 'John'
  inner join DocumentAttributes da2
   on da2.Name = 'CustomerId'
  inner join DocumentAttributeValues dav2
   on dav2.AttributeId = da2.AttributeId
    and dav2.Value = '5'
```

This one picks out the attributes, then finds which documents have all of them. It might perform better, as there’s one less table to process:

```
--  Bottom-up
SELECT xx.DocumentId
 from (--  All documents with name "John"
       select dav.DocumentId
        from DocumentAttributes da
         inner join DocumentAttributeValues dav
          on dav.AttributeId = da.AttributeId
        where da.Name = 'Name'
         and dav.Value = 'John'
       --  This combines the two sets, with "all" keeping any duplicate entries
       union all
       --  All documents with CustomerId = "5"
       select dav.DocumentId
        from DocumentAttributes da
         inner join DocumentAttributeValues dav
          on dav.AttributeId = da.AttributeId
        where da.Name = 'CustomerId'
         and dav.Value = '5') xx  --  Have to give the subquery an alias
  group by xx.DocumentId
  having count(*) = 2
```

While further refinements might be possible, the more more attributes you’re filtering on, the uglier the queries will be. Five attributes max might work ok in SQL, but if you’ve got tons of attributes, a NoSQL solution might be what you’re looking for.

(Please note that, as with my original post, I have not tested this code, so there may be typos or subtle--or not so subtle--errors in here.)

Comment: Can you give an example of an SQL Statement to find what document that has Name = 'John' and CustomerId = '5'?

Comment: Thanks for the SQL. I tried the INNER JOIN scenario and it was faster up to 4 INNER JOINS after that my subquery with group and having was faster, but not fast enough...

Comment: This (lengthy but entertaining) article explains what everyone should know about name-value pairs in relational databases: https://www.simple-talk.com/content/article.aspx?article=292